# Ordered Probit and categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, probit, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I wanted to run a quick and easy (or so I thought) regression on some data I have but now I am starting to doubt whether or not the regression makes any sense. I have seen some similar questions but they don't really answer what I want to know.

I want to run an ordered probit/logit with the dependent variable having five ordinal outcomes. My explanatory variables are: age, work experience, gender, position with-in the organisation, country of origin and so on.

"Gender" will be a dummy variable and "Country of origin" will be coded using dummmies.

"Age" is a categorical variable so it will have values such as 18-25 years, 25-32 years etc. Should I code each group as a dummy variable?

"Position with-in the organisation" is categories such as employee, executive and so on. Should I code each of these as dummy variables?

Work experience are in categories such as 1-2 years, 2-3 years and 5+ years etc. Should I code these as dummy variables?

What I am interested in knowing is that when I only have dummy variables as explanatory variables, will I get meaningful results? For some reason I find it very unintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Results from an ordered logit/probit regression are always unintuitive, but categorical explanatory variables are as meaningful as continuous ones. I'd even say that they are easier to interpret.

For a concrete example, you could look at Dobson, *An Introduction to Generalizer Linear Models*, 2002, 2nd ed., Chapter 8. In her "car preferences" example, the dependent variable is the importance of air conditioning and power steering (three levels: "no or little importance", "important", "very important") and the two explanatory variables are gender (male or female, coded as 1 and 0) and age (18-23, 24-40, >40, coded as age2440 = 1 or 0, and agegt40 = 1 or 0).

Fitting an ordered probit model you get (I've used R, MASS library, polr() function):

```
Coefficients:
   male age2440 agegt40 
-0.3467  0.6817  1.3288 

Intercepts:
  NoImp|Imp Imp|VeryImp 
    0.01844     0.97594
```

Then you can compute the probabilities for women (male = 0) over 40 (age2440 = 0, agegt40 = 1):

```
NoImp     Imp VeryImp 
0.095   0.267   0.638
```

and for men over 40 (male = 1):

```
NoImp     Imp VeryImp 
0.168   0.330   0.502
```

Their difference is the gender partial effect:

```
 NoImp     Imp VeryImp 
-0.073  -0.063   0.136
```

I think that it's meaningful ;-)